How would I paste into cells in google sheets which the cells divided by empty lines instead of each line?
It's a little hard for me to explain, but for instance:

This is text that i want to
put
all in one cell.
[empty]
this is text that i want in another
cell,
without it being being separated
by line?

preferrably an empty cell would be where there is a break between the different cell texts. I'm trying to set up a certain text replacement but the line are divided in a way that certain phrases are multiple lines.
it would be pasted, so i'm trying to figure out how to get this to work



Column A




Text goes here


text continues here but in the same cel as the last one


(empty)


text (more)


text continues here but in the same cel as the last one




It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

ArrayFormula
You can also use this as an alternative solution.
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", A1:A&IF(A1:A="", "¶", "")), "¶")))

This will give you a column where each text chunk is merged into a single row, and empty rows will act as separators.
Sample Output

Reference

ArrayFormula


I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but the following formula will do the job, if the string in the cell is ending with certain characters .?! the next non-empty cell will be added in the same cell.
You can add more special characters, to suit your needs.
=TOCOL(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:A),".?!"))

.

